# SQL column containing array of table row values

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I'm quite new to databases and SQL. I have an assignment, but I don't know how to solve this.

Let's say I have table named `Persons`. It has following columns: `userId` (primary key), `userName` and `tags`.

`Tags` is another table, containing only `id` and `tagName`. Person can have multiple tags, for example: "football", "cooking" etc.

Each tag corresponds to `Tag` table row. But I'm not sure how to achieve this kind of relation. How can I achieve this?

I'm guessing it has to something to do with foreign keys and making persons tag column an array of foreign keys.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You normally want to have a relation table (this is called a many-to-many relationship, or M:M).

```
Persons(id int, name varchar(40)...)

Tags(id int, name varchar(40)....)

PersonTags(id int,
           personid FOREIGN KEY References Persons(id), 
           TagId FOREIGN KEY references Tags(id))
```

This way you can have as many or as few tags as you like, but the tag data isn't stored in-row for the person.  You could potentially store a series of values in a single field, but this is a really terrible idea for a variety of reasons.

Comment: just complementing @JNK's answer.
you can create your foreign key to PERSONS with ON DELETE CASCADE option, which means that when a person is deleted, all tags belonging to it (the record on PersonTags), will be deleted too, but nothing will happen to the TAG itself on the Tags table

Comment: What are the reasons that this is a terrible idea?